# How to group variables to calculate new fields in R?

Tags: r

I have a sample dataframe looks like below:

```
year state district individual_vote total_vote  candidate 
 2010 AZ     1          200             600        a
 2010 AZ     1          400             600        b
 2010 AZ     2          100             300        c
 2010 AZ     2          200             300        d
 2010 MA     1          100            200         e
 2010 MA     2          100            200         f
 2005 AZ     1          100            150         g
 2005 AZ     1          150            200         h
```

I'd like to calculate

1. who the winner is

2.the vote margin of the winner (the difference between winner's vote and the 2nd place).

How do I group them by `year, state, district` and calculate these two fields for each candidate? Thanks!

Comment: New columns would be great.

Comment: I didn't vote any post yet. Since I'm still looking for solutions on calculating the vote margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to create new columns, we `arrange` the data by 'year', 'state', 'district', and 'individual_vote' in `desc`ending order, then we group by 'year', 'state', 'district', create the 'winner' as the `first` 'candidate' and the `vote_margin` as the difference between the first and second observation.  In the `mutate`, we made a conditional approach so that if there is only a single row, it would return the `first` element and if there are more take the difference between the first two

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(year, state, district, desc(individual_vote)) %>%
    group_by(year, state, district) %>%
    mutate(winner = first(candidate),      
        vote_margin = if(n() > 1) individual_vote[1] - individual_vote[2] else 
                first(individual_vote)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
#   year state district individual_vote total_vote candidate winner vote_margin
#  <int> <chr>    <int>           <int>      <int> <chr>     <chr>        <int>
#1  2005 AZ           1             150        200 h         h               50
#2  2005 AZ           1             100        150 g         h               50
#3  2010 AZ           1             400        600 b         b              200
#4  2010 AZ           1             200        600 a         b              200
#5  2010 AZ           2             200        300 d         d              100
#6  2010 AZ           2             100        300 c         d              100
#7  2010 MA           1             100        200 e         e              100
#8  2010 MA           2             100        200 f         f              100
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2005L, 2005L), state = c("AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "MA", "MA", 
"AZ", "AZ"), district = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), individual_vote = c(200L, 
400L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 150L), total_vote = c(600L, 
600L, 300L, 300L, 200L, 200L, 150L, 200L), candidate = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the definition on "vote margin". It is the difference between the winner and the 2nd in place. Sorry for not clarifying it earlier.

Comment: I didn't upvote post yet. Since I just updated the definition on "vote margin."

Answer (score 2):

This code can give you a path to obtain what you wish, as some definitions are not clear for me:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>%
  group_by(year,state,district) %>%
  mutate(Ratio=individual_vote/total_vote,
         Winner=candidate[which.max(Ratio)])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   year, state, district [5]
   year state district individual_vote total_vote candidate Ratio Winner
  <int> <chr>    <int>           <int>      <int> <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
1  2010 AZ           1             200        600 a         0.333 b     
2  2010 AZ           1             400        600 b         0.667 b     
3  2010 AZ           2             100        300 c         0.333 d     
4  2010 AZ           2             200        300 d         0.667 d     
5  2010 MA           1             100        200 e         0.5   e     
6  2010 MA           2             100        200 f         0.5   f     
7  2005 AZ           1             100        150 g         0.667 h     
8  2005 AZ           1             150        200 h         0.75  h
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2005L, 2005L), state = c("AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "MA", "MA", 
"AZ", "AZ"), district = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), individual_vote = c(200L, 
400L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 150L), total_vote = c(600L, 
600L, 300L, 300L, 200L, 200L, 150L, 200L), candidate = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

**Update:**

```
#Code 2
newdf <- df %>%
  arrange(year,state,district,desc(individual_vote)) %>%
  group_by(year,state,district) %>%
  mutate(Winner=candidate[which.max(individual_vote)],
         Diff=c(NA,abs(diff(individual_vote))),
         Margin=ifelse(row_number()==2,Diff,NA)) %>%
  fill(Margin,.direction = "downup") %>%
  mutate(Margin=ifelse(is.na(Margin),individual_vote,Margin)) %>%
  select(-Diff)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   year, state, district [5]
   year state district individual_vote total_vote candidate Winner Margin
  <int> <chr>    <int>           <int>      <int> <chr>     <chr>   <int>
1  2005 AZ           1             150        200 h         h          50
2  2005 AZ           1             100        150 g         h          50
3  2010 AZ           1             400        600 b         b         200
4  2010 AZ           1             200        600 a         b         200
5  2010 AZ           2             200        300 d         d         100
6  2010 AZ           2             100        300 c         d         100
7  2010 MA           1             100        200 e         e         100
8  2010 MA           2             100        200 f         f         100
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the definition on "vote margin". It is the difference between the winner and the 2nd in place. Sorry for not clarifying it earlier.

Comment: @Yvonne Hi Yvonne, hope you are fine. Sorry for my confusion. I have added an update with the new definitions. Hope that helps you :)